# Corner Repair Small Chips

Tags: walls

I have a couple of spots right along the corner edge, where the paint and (I think) joint compound have come off, when the wallpaper was removed. What is the easiest way to repair this?

Comment: Pictures would help, but it sounds like just adding a bit of drywall mud back on.  Remove any loose mud/paint and clean.